# Customizing cv2.circle

Tags: python, opencv

Im using following code to draw circle around face.

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.circle(img, ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )), int (h / 2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
```

however the thickness of drawn circle is entirely green. Is there any ways to make few percentage (say 30% )of the circle to be pink?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to draw two arcs, colored independently, using [`cv2.ellipse`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.ellipse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you could use [`cv2.ellipse()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.ellipse) to draw the two arcs individually.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones((400,400,3), np.uint8) * 255

# See:
#   http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.ellipse
#   http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

circ_center = (200,200)
circ_radius = 150
circ_thick  = 12
circ_axes   = (circ_radius,circ_radius)

# cv2.ellipse(img, center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]])    
cv2.ellipse(img, circ_center, circ_axes, 0,  0,  90, (255,0,0), circ_thick, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.ellipse(img, circ_center, circ_axes, 0, 90, 360, (0,255,0), circ_thick, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.imwrite("circ1.png", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Produces:

[image: Arcs1]

Now, the arcs have rounded edges.  This may or may not be an issue for you.  I'm not sure if there's a better way in OpenCV, but one way that I've created thick lines with flat edges is to build the thick lines out of many thin lines.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.ones((400,400,3), np.uint8) * 255

# See:
#   http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.ellipse
#   http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

circ_center = (200,200)
circ_radius = 150
circ_thick  = 12

def draw_arc(img, center, rad, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color, thickness, lineType, thick=1):
    for r in range(rad,rad+thickness):
        cv2.ellipse(img, center, (r,r), angle, startAngle, endAngle, color, thick, lineType)

draw_arc(img, circ_center, circ_radius, 0,  0,  90, (255,0,0), circ_thick, cv2.LINE_AA)
draw_arc(img, circ_center, circ_radius, 0, 90, 360, (0,255,0), circ_thick, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.imwrite("circ2.png", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Produces:

[image: Arcs2]

You can adjust the starting and ending points of the coloring by adjusting the `startAngle` and `endAngle` parameters.  There are a few other parameters you may want to adjust in there, but this should give you an idea of one approach.

You could also just draw a complete circle and layer an arc on top of it corresponding to what you want colored different, which may be easier in the end.